# yocto kernel ti network error

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, yocto

i'm getting a network interface error when building for the 4.4 ti staging kernel. All layers are in the morty branch.
The image is a core-image-minimal.

*Configuring network interfaces... ifup: unknown address type "inet"*

With the following config:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " automake "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " binutils "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " binutils-symlinks "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " cpp cpp-symlinks "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " gcc gcc-symlinks "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " g++ g++-symlinks "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " gettext "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " make cmake "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " libstdc++ libstdc++-dev "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " file "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " coreutils "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " git "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " wpa-supplicant "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append =  " wl18xx-fw "
IMAGE_FEATURES_append =  " ssh-server-dropbear "

DISTRO_FEATURES = "wifi"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-ti-staging"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-ti-staging = "4.4%"

MACHINE ?= "beaglebone"

CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL = " pru-icss  ti-cgt-pru uio-test-pruss dhcp-client"

DL_DIR = "/home/auke/workspace/yocto/DOWNLOADS"
TMPDIR = "/home/auke/workspace/yocto/TEMP"

DISTRO = "poky"

EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks"

USER_CLASSES = "image-mklibs image-prelink"

PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"

RM_OLD_IMAGE = "1"

INHERIT += "rm_work"

CONF_VERSION = "1"
```

With the layer section:

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

    BBLAYERS ?= " \
      /home/auke/workspace/yocto/poky/meta \
      /home/auke/workspace/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
      /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-qt5  \
      /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking  \
      /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe  \
      /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python  \
      /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-ti  \
      "
```

kernel output:

```
Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.49-gc2eed4ada2 (auke@XX) (gcc version 6.2.0 (GCC) ) #1 PREEMPT Fri Oct 27 17:03:16 CEST 2017
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt:Machine model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
[    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 48 MiB at 0x9d000000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon)
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129920
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=PARTUUID=ca52207f-02 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 457972K/524288K available (7168K kernel code, 281K rwdata, 2400K rodata, 1024K init, 280K bss, 17164K reserved, 49152K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 496 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
[    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0800000   (8160 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc0b00000 - 0xc0c00000   (1024 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc0c00000 - 0xc0c46430   ( 282 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0c46430 - 0xc0c8c674   ( 281 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0xfa200000 (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts
[    0.000000] OMAP clockevent source: timer2 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000013] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000032] clocksource: timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000042] OMAP clocksource: timer1 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000186] clocksource_probe: no matching clocksources found
[    0.000342] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000366] WARNING: Your 'console=ttyO0' has been replaced by 'ttyS0'
[    0.000372] This ensures that you still see kernel messages. Please
[    0.000377] update your kernel commandline.
[    0.000398] Calibrating delay loop... 996.14 BogoMIPS (lpj=4980736)
[    0.089244] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.089361] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.089371] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.090086] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.090431] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100060
[    0.091150] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.092308] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.102156] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    0.102484] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.102509] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
[    0.105825] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.106931] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.108611] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.121575] omap_hwmod: debugss: _wait_target_disable failed
[    0.199235] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.229225] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.234445] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    0.247770] No ATAGs?
[    0.247795] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    0.286328] edma 49000000.edma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    0.289141] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /ocp/l4_wkup@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.289203] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: could not find pctldev for node /ocp/l4_wkup@44c00000/scm@210000/pinmux@800/pinmux_i2c2_pins, deferring probe
[    0.289465] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.289519] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.289559] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.289566] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.289586] PTP clock support registered
[    0.289631] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.290610] omap-mailbox 480c8000.mailbox: omap mailbox rev 0x400
[    0.290910] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.292028] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer1
[    0.300929] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.301627] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.301672] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.301711] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.301775] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.301791] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.301914] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.302375] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.302389] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.302395] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.302400] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.303239] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    0.305301] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    0.311672] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.312684] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.312730] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.312737] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.312780] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O].
[    0.314434] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 246)
[    0.314451] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.314458] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.314599] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.315769] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568
[    0.369506] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 10 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.372842] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 158, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    0.964290] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.969353] omap_rng 48310000.rng: OMAP Random Number Generator ver. 20
[    0.976172] [drm] Initialized
[    0.991181] brd: module loaded
[    0.999880] loop: module loaded
[    1.005062] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.082111] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6
[    1.088250] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: detected phy mask fffffffe
[    1.095391] libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
[    1.099435] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720
[    1.109352] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: Detected MACID = 88:c2:55:8d:d4:3a
[    1.116139] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: cpts: overflow check period 500 (jiffies)
[    1.124922] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.130860] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.136005] cpuidle: enable-method property 'ti,am3352' found operations
[    1.143720] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    1.263262] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.275550] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.281274] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    1.288246] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.293083] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.297583] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    1.316679] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.329927] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    1.336149] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL16G 14.8 GiB 
[    1.346035]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.349292] random: fast init done
[    1.356467] tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2
[    1.362545] at24 0-0050: 32768 byte 24c256 EEPROM, writable, 1 bytes/write
[    1.372821] mmc1: new high speed MMC card at address 0001
[    1.378866] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 S10004 3.56 GiB 
[    1.383744] mmcblk1boot0: mmc1:0001 S10004 partition 1 4.00 MiB
[    1.389902] mmcblk1boot1: mmc1:0001 S10004 partition 2 4.00 MiB
[    1.504375] tda998x 0-0070: found TDA19988
[    1.509700] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: bound 0-0070 (ops tda998x_ops)
[    1.515798] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.522454] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    1.528719] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: No connectors reported connected with modes
[    1.535924] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768
[    1.550021] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[    1.561257] tilcdc 4830e000.lcdc: fb0:  frame buffer device
[    1.592722] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
[    1.712912] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: bus 2 rev0.11 at 100 kHz
[    1.720454] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    1.726141] ALSA device list:
[    1.729129]   No soundcards found.
[    1.746736] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[    1.762789] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.770985] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    1.783587] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.788106] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
INIT: version 2.88 booting
Starting udev
[    2.343032] udevd[102]: starting version 3.2
[    2.403136] udevd[103]: starting eudev-3.2
[    3.714767] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
Populating dev cache
hwclock: can't open '/dev/misc/rtc': No such file or directory
Fri Oct 27 15:32:02 UTC 2017
INIT: Entering runlevel: 5misc/rtc': No such file or directory
Configuring network interfaces... ifup: unknown address type "inet"
Starting system message bus: dbus.
Starting Dropbear SSH server: Generating key, this may take a while...
Public key portion is:
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCGOZUSxXTHMAYlklJBENfDJ8k3lexNyEnddclBHJ7bq5SBiugD2RQH7L5ZDsCzXnm8GvO4j6zepIJDINNy0UaUWDDK/i+QW5fecMvOqo7uXKrxCWiUhf2cRH1puFQWuvO6Hg6L6tsqSEs1oxQwYDErDy6WnK0+KWfRLeo/WoNAHpYv/jMs3B7FrUL9TSvQ6S9BqPZbo7eGNBGMpywZpLqDW3F73NelW4zmgFrLuEwEEE5FxEkmdoBwQqDcG77rhYdw5ZkC26Xig3SyTGU11L8Rrd+6cw2wGih8QtttPF/S0iZxbGuWOw2asClkaGZZmzwoXlTpgRmMUNIPPArD2MgH root@beaglebone
Fingerprint: md5 8c:25:cb:4c:02:0e:1a:9e:cd:4f:8f:10:b3:a3:5d:42
dropbear.
hwclock: can't open '/dev/misc/rtc': No such file or directory
Starting syslogd/klogd: done

Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.2.2 beaglebone /dev/ttyS0
```

I have had internet working using the non meta-ti layer. Any tips suggestions
are highly appreciated.
Auke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your distro appears to not have `ipv4/6` configured, hence BusyBox drops all networking from its config.  I'd say to do `DISTRO_FEATURES += "ipv4 ipv6"`, but it's normally the default... Looking closer at your config above, you simply overwrite all the defaults with `DISTRO_FEATURES = "wifi"`, while you probably want `DISTRO_FEATURES += "wifi"` instead - to append, not overwrite...

Comment: ,@SherulHohman, thank you for the append/overwrite issue. I'll do a clean build and see (most likely) if i have a working ip-stack.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through **/var/log/messages** I was notified on the BusyBox version, checking the configuration I noticed that the default configuration has ipv4/6 disabled.
(Pff why?)

In order to fix it:

```
bitbake -c menuconfig busybox  
bitbake busybox
```

check all settings!